# Loki freezes after screen locks itself

Tags: release-loki, greeter, crash

Loki turns off the screen after 10-15 Minutes of inactivity. At the same time it looks the screen automatically.

When I wake the computer, the log in screen appears as it should and I can log in. But after logging in, the display stays black. I can see and move the cursor but that's all.

I can change to tty and restart lightdm with `sudo service lightdm restart` but since this closes every opened program this isn't really helpful at all.

Any Ideas?

[image]
Somehow I manged to "revive" the screen once and I found that this ↑ prompt appears when the screen was locked. The prompt appears many, many times (I needed to press and hold <kbd>esc</kbd> for 10 seconds to close all these windows). Maybe this relates to freezing the screen?

Answer (score 1):

I have this bug also on stable release of Loki.
It's probably this bug [1635254 (desktop freezes & misbehaves on login)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/appcenter/+bug/1617687)

As a temporary fix i changed Settings => Security & Privacy, unchecked lock after screen turn off.